# How to change Collation in a Synapse Serverless Database

Tags: azure, serverless, azure-synapse, collation

How to change the collation of a Synapse *Serverless* database?  Specifically Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC_UTF8, as that seems to be recommended, and I'm trying to performance tune.

```
alter database MyDatabase collate Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC_UTF8
```

Results in the error

```
The database MyDatabase could not be exclusively locked to perform the operation.
```

OK, set single user

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
```

Results in the error

```
SINGLE_USER is not supported for ALTER DATABASE.
```

[Microsoft learn has an article on switching Collation in Synapse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/reference-collation-types)

But the text mentions

"To change the default collation for **dedicated** SQL pool database,..."

I can't find anything for *Serverless* in the documentation.

[Microsoft Learn also has an article on switching to Single User](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/set-a-database-to-single-user-mode?view=sql-server-ver16)

But it just gives the same command (which errors), or using the GUI in SSMS - which doesn't have same options when I check it on a *serverless* database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it.  Although the command to set single user doesn't work in Synapse Serverless, I just worked around it by booting everyone off /restarting SSMS myself, and only connecting the query window (not object explorer), so only one connection was present.

Then I was able to execute

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2_UTF8
```

That worked for 1 / 2 database. The other, was still complaining.  For that one, I ran the following code:

```
 select DB_NAME(database_id), 'kill '+cast(session_id as varchar(10)), *
from sys.dm_exec_sessions
where DB_NAME(database_id) = 'datawarehouseserverless'
order by 1
```

Then killed whatever came up. And at that point, was able to run the ALTER DATABSE...COLATE command.