# Collation conflict in Microsoft database project for Azure Synapse Analytics Serverless SQL Pool

Tags: visual-studio, azure-sql-database, azure-synapse, database-project, sql-server-collation

I am working on a Lakehouse project in Synapse Azure. I have created a Serverless SQL Pool with the collation **Latin1_General_100_BIN2_UTF8**. This collation is recommended by Microsoft for parquet und Delta tables, see MS Doc [Best practices for serverless SQL pool in Azure Synapse Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/best-practices-serverless-sql-pool#use-proper-collation-to-utilize-predicate-pushdown-for-character-columns).

The collation of the master database is the **SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS** as default.

I have created a database project in Visual Studio 2022 (Version 17.8.5) for deployment purposes. I did the required settings, like setting the target platform to "Azure Synapse Analytics Serverless SQL Pool" and the collation "Latin1_General_100_BIN2_UTF8" under the "Database Settings".

When I run Schema compare, I receive the following error:

> Unexpected exception caught during population of source model: Cannot
> resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
> and "Latin1_General_100_BIN2_UTF8" in the UNION operation.

Then, I tried to compare the Schema with Azure Data Studio, I got the same exception.

I do not want to use the default collation of the master database. I am not sure if this is a bug, as the Database Project considering the collation of the master database instead of the target database, or if I am missing some other configurations.

Answer (score -1):

You can check if the collation **Latin1_General_100_BIN2_UTF8** is applied to the database you are working with by using the syntax below to check the current collation:

```
SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('db02', 'Collation') AS Collation;
```

The [DatabasePropertyEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/databasepropertyex-transact-sql?toc=/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/toc.json&bc=/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/breadcrumb/toc.json&view=azure-sqldw-latest&preserve-view=true) function, when given '**Collation**' as the property parameter, retrieves the current collation settings for the specified database.

To modify the default collation for a serverless SQL pool database, you can utilize the `ALTER DATABASE` statement. For example:

```
ALTER DATABASE db02 COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2_UTF8
```

**Results:**

[image]

**Reference:** SO thread [How to change Collation in a Synapse Serverless Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76964620/how-to-change-collation-in-a-synapse-serverless-database)

[Database collation support for Synapse SQL in Azure Synapse Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/reference-collation-types#change-collation)

Comment: @Dileeprajanrayan, thanks for your comments. The collation is set correctly.

Comment: @NaveenSharma,thanks for your comments. Unfortuently, the problem still exists. The provided answer did not solve the problem.

Comment: so, to be more precise, the provided did not help solving the problem. As it is mentioned in the question, the database collation and the DB project configs are set correclty. I tend to believe that is a bug from the SSDT.

Comment: @Zaid salem could you please confirm if you have created a database in your serverless pool?
if you have created the database in such case, you can ALTER the collation.